# What argument can stands before the client command in IMAP4?

Tags: email, parameters, command, protocols, imap

I'm reading **RFC 3501** and there are many examples like this:

```
C: a001 LOGIN SMITH SESAME
S: a001 OK LOGIN completed
```

So, what is this **a001** before the command LOGIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command's tag, chosen by the client. IMAP permits clients to issue several commands at the same time. The server processes all, and then reports to the client that a particular command is now done.

```
C: a001 LOGIN SMITH SESAME
```

A new command starts, tagged a001.

```
S: a001 OK human-readable text goes here
```

Command a001 is now done, without errors.